# Cloudflare Workers: Request to Google Maps API failed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have a javascript project that I need help, which is to build a cache layer using cloudflare workers and cloudflare KV.

These were my given tasks:

- Send API requests to a new url on cloudflare like:  `https://maps.shiply.com` rather than  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictionsJson?1ssw&4sen-GB&5sGB&6m6&1m2&1d34.5626609&2d-8.649357199999999&2m2&1d60.8608663&2d33.9165549&9sgeocode&15e3&20sDDC1BA1D-F381-44DA-9F99-B6F465F95056ap5a8xfuid3p&21m1&2e1&callback=_xdc_.`*`24ids0&key=`*`APIKEY&token=TOKEN`
- The [cloudflare worker](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/) script first checks the [Cloudflare KV](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/kv/#reading-key-value-pairs) to see if the response has been saved in the past.
- If it has been saved in the past, return the KV.
- If it has not been saved in the past, forward the request onto Google Maps API, save the response in [KV](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/kv/#writing-key-value-pairs) and return the response

```
export default {
  async fetch(request, env) {
    try {
      const { pathname } = new URL(request.url);
      const [, key, value] = pathname.split("/");

      if (!key) {
        return new Response("A key is required in the URL path", {
          status: 400,
        });
      }

      if (request.method === "GET") {
        // Check if the response has been saved in the past
        const savedValue = await env.MAPS.get(key, {
          namespace: env.NAMESPACE_ID,
        });

        if (savedValue) {
          // If it has been saved, return the saved value
          return new Response(savedValue, { status: 200 });
        } else {
          // If it has not been saved, forward the request to Google Maps API
          const response = await fetch(
            request.url.replace(
              "maps.mapior.workers.dev",
              `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictionsJson?1s${key}&4sen-GB&5sGB&6m6&1m2&1d34.5626609&2d-8.649357199999999&2m2&1d60.8608663&2d33.9165549&9sgeocode&15e3&20sDDC1BA1D-F381-44DA-9F99-B6F465F95056ap5a8xfuid3p&21m1&2e1&callback=_xdc_._24ids0&key=API_KEY&token=MY_TOKEN`
            )
          );

          if (!response.ok) {
            return new Response(
              `Request to Google Maps API failed with status code ${response.status}`,
              { status: response.status }
            );
          }

          const responseText = await response.text();

          // Save the response in the Key-Value store
          await env.MAPS.put(key, responseText, {
            namespace: env.NAMESPACE_ID,
          });

          // Return the response from Google Maps API
          return new Response(responseText, { status: 200 });
        }
      } else if (request.method === "PUT") {
        // Store the value in the Key-Value store
        if (!value) {
          return new Response("A value is required in the URL path", {
            status: 400,
          });
        }

        await env.MAPS.put(key, value, { namespace: env.NAMESPACE_ID });
        return new Response(`Saved in KV: ${key} = ${value}`);
      } else {
        return new Response("Unsupported method", { status: 405 });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return new Response(e.stack, { status: 500 });
    }
  },
};
```

As you can see from my above script, i was able to complete most of the tasks, but i have no idea about the google map AutocompletionService, the documentation were very confusing for a beginner like me.

When i run the above code in cloudfare workers enviornment, i am getting this error due to the request failure to google maps api:
`502 Bad Gateway, content-length:54 content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8 Request to Google Maps API failed with status code 502`

A Screenshot from my cloudflare workers dashboard where i am currently working on: [My Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkvfm.png)

Something is wrong with the `URL` or my implementation.

Please help, i am a beginner and haven't worked on something like this before, can you please help me out.

As an output i need to see a google maps api response and store it as a value in [cloudflarekv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QWYq.png) like so.

Comment: can anybody help please, if you still aren't sure what i am expecting to solve or if there is any problem with the issue i submitted please let me know.

Comment: I have set up a new key with no domain or IP restrictions for testing. still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: Caching is not allowed. Read their TOS.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for ways to misuse a service.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of how the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and its [Autocomplete service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete) work, there are at *least two* reasons why what you are attempting seems problematic (not recommended):

1. The JavaScript API is designed to run in the users' browsers and send requests **directly** to Google servers. Anything that interferes with that direct connection is bound to cause problems. *Unpredictable* problems. The sensible recommendation to avoid problems is to use the API **only** as described in the documentation. **If it's not documented, it's not an API.**
2. Caching is disallowed by the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/). There are a few exceptions in the [Google Maps Platform Service Specific Terms](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms) but none that allow caching entire API responses.

If you are concerned about having sensible caching, note that the Place Autocomplete service already sets `cache-control: private, max-age=300` so the users' browsers will cache API responses for a short time, so duplicate requests are not sent in the short term.